# DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString adds one hour to it mysteriously :S

Tags: .net, datetime, compact-framework

I want to add the current date/time to an XML document
So i use something like this

```
   XmlAttribute receivedDateTime = SettingsFile.CreateAttribute("ReceivedDateTime");
receivedDateTime.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();  

  Debug.WriteLine("Adding Date Time in addMessage method : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
  Debug.WriteLine("Short Time Only: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
  Debug.WriteLine("Long Time Only: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
  Debug.WriteLine("Local Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
```

But it automatically adds 1 hour to the actual time! 
So if the actual time is `10.15 AM`,

the debug messages print

```
Adding Date Time in addMessage method : 8/3/10 11:15 AM
Short Time Only: 11:15 AM
Long Time Only: 11:15:51 AM
Local Time: 8/3/10 11:15:51 AM
```

And I am running this on a mobile emulator and double checked that the emulator time is consistent with my PC's time!

I know this must be a very minor mistake... So if anyone can point it out, it would be much appreciated. Does it have to anything to do with GMT or UTC or any culture?

Comment: What is your timezone (on your host and on your emulator)?  Does it show the correct UTC time (ie. DateTime.UtcNow)?

Comment: How do you know the time is "10:15 AM"? That claim doesn't stand with the scientific method.

Comment: Ahh... Even though the time was correct on the emulator, the GMT time zone was set to a different one :) That did the trick :) Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the mobile device set to not use daylight savings time? and is set to the same time but not the same local time offset?

Comment: It wasnt actually DST, but the GMT time zone :) But your answer made me go and actually check it :)